# how to implement input filter and validation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, user-input

I am a newbie in zendframework. I am using zendframework version 2.

I have a ClientForm class which is inheriting from Zend\Form\Form.

```
class Client extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null, $options = array())
    {
        if (null == $name) $name = 'ClientFrom';
        parent::__construct($name, $options);

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'clientName',
            'type' => 'Text'
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'address1',
            'type' => 'Text'
        ));
    }
}
```

I need to implement validation and filtering for the above form.

**Rules for Validation**

```
'clientName' => required, min = 3, max = 25
```

**Rules for Filter**

```
'clientName' => [a-zA-Z0-9_ ]
```

**Questions**

1. Can I implement this rules and filter in the same class as Form (without creating a new input filter class)
2. Please show me example on how to implement above rules on my above class.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'clientName',
        'type' => 'text',
        'required' => true,             
        'validators' => array(
             new Validator\RegexValidator('/^#[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]$/'),
             new Validator\StringLength(array('min'=>3 ,'max' => 25))
         )             
    ));
```

Comment: I'm curious, does this actually work? I can't see this going by the source alone Oo

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`Zend\InputFilter`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html)-Component that you'd use for this kind of task. There's a lot of examples out there, some programatical ones like [here](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html) or some configurational ones like [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/validator.md#use-together-with-zend-framework-2-forms) or [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md#a-complete-example-using-zendform).

The later two being examples used for specific Doctrine-Validators, but you can use them for any normal `Zend\InputFilter`, too.

Comment: I went through several example all are abstract. Can you just implement and show me for the above code?

Comment: I'm at work right now and not yet in the mood. Please see the later links. They document VERY WELL how the `Zend\Form` component should be used. It will help you a great deal! PS: Your "Rules for Filter" is actually a "Rule for Validation" ;) Filters are things like StringTrim, StripTags, etc..

Comment: If the downvoters would care to explain there vote, that'd be great. The resources I gave are the most suggested way to implement InputFilters for Forms. Everything else is basically non-OOP-workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have no code yourself yet ... well.

> 'clientName' => required, min = 3, max = 25

This one isnt too difficult, heres some easy code ... ill write it extremely simple and readable, you can shorten the if-statements if you want:

```
if(!empty($clientName)) {
    if(!($clientName > 25)) {
        if(!($clientName < 3)) {
            echo "valid name!";
        }
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

> 'clientName' => [a-zA-Z0-9_ ]

Either you use RegEx or string-functions where you only allow these specific characters.

Comment: I know, but i suppose that its the easiest one to understand.

Comment: i can do this way for normal php project. instead zend provide some fine grained solutions for validation and filtering. so i need help on that pattern.

Comment: Thats what i even wrote: "you can shorten the if-statements if you want". Ofc you can write all of it in one if statement, but if the TE asks for such a code, i suppose this code is easier than some difficult to read code.

Comment: @user247947 Woops, Zend-Framework ... i completely ignored that. Got no experience with Zend. Ill retreat in shame. :>

Comment: mhh... put your hand on zf and see .. its awesome!